# Vertical scroll bar doesn't show when it should in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I have a long page and it should show the vertical scroll bar in IE but it doesn't. I can click on a button and the scroll bars appear then they disappear when the page is reloaded.

Here is the css

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html, body, form{height:100%}

body{position:relative;width:100%;}/*opera 9.5 fix*/

body 
{
    font-family:Trebuchet MS, Lucida Grande, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
/* ---Layout--- */
#wrapper{ 
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    margin:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:-100px;/*footer height*/

} 
* html #wrapper{height:100%}
#header{
    background: url(images/header.png);
    height:89px;
    border-top:100px solid #fff;/* soak up negative margin*/
}

#header_inner{
    width:960px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;  
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, what's the reasoning behind the selector "* html #wrapper{height:100%}" when you have #wrapper defined above it? (browser hack of some kind?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
html { height: 100.1%; margin-bottom: 1px; }
```

Comment: im begging to think its something else. I can see that very small space created by the .1% but it still doesnt show the footer until I ctrl f5 then i can see the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use

```
html, body, form{height:100%}
```

Will there be a scrollbar if you remove that line?

Comment: Setting the html element to 100.1% is a wee hack to ensure that you don't have a jarring pixel shift issue in non-IE browsers without scrollbar guttering when the height of the frame changes. This is actually on of the best things about IE (not often you get to say that).

Setting the height of the body and form elements however seems unusual.

Answer (score -1):

May be won't help, but really, try getting rid of height: 100% on everything. A lot of times it causes problems with IE. If you can't, try adding

```
hasLayout: true;
```

to the form.

Comment: #element { height:1%; } is probably the best approach to fix the hasLayout IE issue, since it's non-proprietary.